# AI library framework in Ada

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ada

I'm looking for an Ada constructed framework for AI. I think Ada would be perfect for implementing temporal and stochastic paradigms due to its tasking and real-time mechanisms, but did not find anyone who tried to make such a libraries. Actually I did not find strong implementations on other languages too. For C# I found http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/1/56/, and for C++ I found http://mind.sourceforge.net/cpp.html but both did not get much popularity. Maybe java has good AI libraries too, but I do not know. So, do you know an Ada implementation? Would it be useful for more anyone? If you know libraries from other languages, it would be useful to know and compare the implementation models in java, for example. Thanks.

Comment: Pardon my illiteracy, but is Ada still in usage today?

Comment: Yes. Highly. Mainly for embedded safe/critical software, in avionics, medical and nuclear industry. The language got a bigger upgrade in 95, in 2005 suffered other upgrade to include several oo facilities, and more recently a new language upgrade is going to be release in 2012 (Ada 2012), which will include several multicores paradigms. There is a free/opensource compiler in <http://libre.adacore.com/libre/>, which made a release in 2011, but you can find several other available. I feel very comfortable programming on it.

Comment: Thank you for little education :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a few resources:

Book, rather old, though (1989): [Artificial Intelligence With Ada](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070033501)

Looks like some kind of university student dissertation: [MUTANTS: A generic genetic algorithm toolkit for Ada 95](http://www.permutationcity.co.uk/projects/mutants/MutantsReport.pdf.gz)

Dmitry Kazakov's [AI stuff](http://www.dmitry-kazakov.de/ai.htm), mostly fuzzy logic. (Dmitry writes *really* nice software.)

Answer (score 1):

I once had a school AI project that used the [CLIPS AI builder library](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/).

Since I avoid coding in C where I don't have to, I made an [Ada Binding to it](http://telepath.com/~dennison/Ted/AdaClips/AdaClips.html), which I believe is licensed without restriction. If you want it, have at.

I used it to build an expert system capable of [playing a user's opening moves](http://telepath.com/~dennison/Ted/Fodderbot/Fodderbot.html) in Empire. All the code is either in Ada, or Clips' expert system specification language.

Comment: Thank you TED. It will be very usefull for sure.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jade.tilab.com/)'s a potentially useful Java library. I haven't heard of any Ada libraries. Ada is a great language, though.

[Here](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/)'s some genetic stuff.