# Where to start on making an A.i. in Ada

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, ada

This is my first question on Stackoverflow.

I'm wanting to make an A.I.

using the `Ada Programming Language`

Where  do I start and what Libraries are available?

My OS is `Ubuntu 11.10`

My Language `Ada 95`

Comment: Where do you start?! Kind of depends what you want to do.

Comment: I want to be able to talk to my text.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "talk to my text"?  Are you talking about voice recognition?  Voice synthesis?

Comment: I meant by text like an interpreter. that loops around and processes what I said.

Comment: Ok, that's not really what the word "text" means.

Comment: What does this have to do with computer vision? In any case, good luck with your dissertation. Because this is post-doc level work, like Watson-level stuff if you want it to do more than "just talk".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a discussion already with some nice links to books and frameworks: [AI library framework in Ada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852149/ai-library-framework-in-ada)

Also Google gives a link: Ada for Artificial Intelligence: http://mind.sourceforge.net/ada.html

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is called [natural language processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing). You can start by looking up various articles on it, and looking at the Wikipedia article on [chatterboxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatterbot), which is one of the names for AI bots programming to interface with humans. Your next step would be to [Google](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sugexp=cqn&gs_nf=1&cp=11&gs_id=b&xhr=t&q=natural%20language%20processing&pf=p&safe=active&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=natural%20lan&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=95e6f5d098e4da22&biw=1600&bih=775&ion=1) natural language processing, which is becoming an increasingly popular subject. There are even [courses](https://www.coursera.org/nlp/auth/welcome) on it that you could take.

You should have a least a small amount of calculus, algebra, statistics, and some prior programming knowledge before attempting to program a chatterbox, although nothing's technically required. Good luck!

Note: what you'll learn isn't specific to the Ada language. I recommend looking at izhak's answer for that.

Comment: Thank you, but a chatter bot is not what I want I want her to be able to learn and think and advance to be able to do mare then just talk.

Comment: What do you mean by 'more than just talk'?

Comment: I mean I am going to interface it with other programs. so it can control them.